# TinyMCE security question: How do you prevent malicious input?

Tags: php, javascript, security, codeigniter, tinymce

How do you prevent malicious input in WYSIWYG editors like TinyMCE?

I have a system with users who are not "tech savvy" (so no WMD) and need a rich text editor that posts its content into a database.

I'm worried about scripting attacks and malicious input code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you only want safe html then you should use the [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).   If you want to protect against XSS and block all html then you should use `$var=htmlspcialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES);`

Comment: +1 for HTML Purifier. Works really well and lets you customise what you want and what you want not at the level of single tag or even  single attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent that input from the client side.  You can add things to get in the way (or try), but it will always be trivial to submit malicious code.  You NEED to sanitize in PHP.

ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS escape user submitted content before displaying it (`htmlentities` will **usually** take care of that for you).

If you want the ability to have HTML submitted (as you say you want WYSIWYG), then you'll need to white-list sanitize the HTML that was submitted.  When I say white-list, I mean both tag name and attribute.

I'm not that familiar with CodeIgniter, but I did find [this](http://www.jonwinstanley.com/2009/05/using-html-purifier-in-code-igniter-to-clean-user-generated-content/) which looks like it may do what you want...

Answer (score -5):

Use [JQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Comment: javascript can be ignored by an attacker, this will not stop malicious input.

Comment: <H1><B>***NEVER***</B></H1> rely on client-side validation

Comment: Client side validation is useful and if used correctly enhances the user experience and usability, but it must ALWAYS be accompanied by server side validation. When i'm lazy i always start by server side validation and THEN implement the same checks on the client.